# Not disposing the stream , but resetting the counter stream value to 0 and listening to it again

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have a counter bloc and showing the counter on second page, I want to reset the counter value to 0(ZERO) on navigating back to first page or on pressing back button **without disposing the stream** so that I can listen to stream throughout the app.

In short whenever returning to second page the stream count should start from 0.

**CounterBloc.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';

class CounterBloc {
  int _counter = 0;
  StreamController<int> _countController = StreamController<int>.broadcast();

  Stream<int> get counterStream => _countController.stream;
  StreamSink<int> get counterSink => _countController.sink;

  void incrementCounter() {
    _counter++;
    counterSink.add(_counter);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new method (action) inside your Bloc.

```
  void resetCounter() {
    _counter = 0;
    counterSink.add(_counter);
  }
```