# Would having multiple compasses in one app work?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter so I apologize if this seems extremely easy to solve. I'm making an app which uses two compasses. They are put into two separate pages. When I open up the first page, the first compass works just fine. However, when I open up the second page, the second compass moves for a bit then completely stops working. When I try going back to the first page, the first compass stops working as well. I think this is because both compasses uses the same stream but I'm not too sure. The code to make the compasses I took from here: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_compass/example. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have stated there can be 2 suggestive solutions from me that could for you:

1. You are not disposing the stream using the dispose method

   @override
   void dispose() {
   compassController.close();
   super.dispose();
   }
2. If disposing the stream also does not work you can use Navigator.pushReplacement instead of Navigator.push which will remove the previous screen because when you push and pop the elements are not disposed(I'm still figuring the reasons behind this)

Comment: You're right I did forget to dispose the stream, but it says "Undefined name 'compassController'". How do I find the controller for this stream? Do I sift through the files in the package?

Comment: Actually once you have created a stream can't close a stream without controllers that point at the stream. A found a very simple example that will help you figure out how to use streams properly so do check it out.. 
 Also if you find my answer helpful kindly upvote the original answer :)   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921398/how-to-dispose-of-a-stream-controller-flutter.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm still a little confused. Do I make my own controller or is there already an existing controller from the package?

Comment: It's okay if that was a bit confusing. There is this solution and get bit of info regarding streams. https://youtu.be/nQBpOIHE4eE check this video out it explains every thing in a very easy manner. :)